# Git: teammate overwrote files in our remote origin repository so that they no longer contain our latest changes. Fix?

Tags: git, github

I brought the last 'good' commit down to my local repository by doing:

```
git checkout the_SHA_I_wanted
git reset --hard
```

I am now missing my teammate's changes, affecting only 4 files (luckily). How can I grab the latest version of her four files from the remote repository and use them to 'replace' (overwrite) those 4 files in my local repository? (*or, what is this procedure called, so I can research it?*) After that, I plan to push up to the remote without pulling.

We are not git-savvy, so would it be easier to manually copy her files directly into my xCode project and, as I said before, do a push without pulling?

Comment: Sounds like there is a lot of fundamental holes in your Git knowledge - I'd recommend reading at least the first 3 chapters of the free [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) book

Comment: Agreed. If only we weren't so rushed with this project, but it's clear that sucking at Git is costing us time.

Comment: To prevent this in the future, make sure everybody knows not to `--force` a `git push`.

Comment: I would love to know how she pulled this off...I don't think it was by forcing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just four files and the problem is solved by copying them, then you've already answered your own question. Suppose you did want to pull those four files from the remote repository. You have a couple of options.

1. Clone the remote repository locally and then copy files from that local copy to your repo.
2. Run `git fetch` to update your remote. Then you can do something like `git origin/master:show path/to/file.ext > path/to/file.ext` to get individual files locally.

Then you can just add the files and push as you mentioned. (You'll have to give push the `-f` option since you're changing the remote history.) You probably want to keep a backup of the remote branch just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your teammate push her changes to a new branch, then you can pull & merge.